# Replace absolute urls in post content fetched from headless WordPress with next.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, next.js, headless-cms

Been searching for a couple of days now and haven't really found anything related to this issue.
URLs in WP post/page content linking to other internal posts/pages are all absolute and when using WP as a headless CMS the domain needs to be replaced.

Gatsby for example has a plugin with a built in feature that does that automatically:
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-wordpress/

```
// Search and Replace Urls across WordPress content.
        searchAndReplaceContentUrls: {
          sourceUrl: "https://source-url.com",
          replacementUrl: "https://replacement-url.com",
```

Is there anything similar available in/for next.js or do you have to do it "manually"?

Comment: Please refer this URL 1) https://wpbeaches.com/updating-wordpress-mysql-database-after-moving-to-a-new-url/ 2) https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/